# Grails 3 parsing of hash map properties with "." in key not working as expected in earlier versions

Tags: grails

We have the following property for our multi-tenant application which helps us find the tenant based on domain.

```
mydomains = [
  'www.google.com': 'tenant1',
  'www.abc.com': 'tenant2'
]
```

In grails2.2.4 we were able to access it as

```
grailsApplication.config.mydomains['www.abc.com']
```

it would correctly give us 'tenant2' in 2.2.4, but in grails 3.3.7 it seems to create a map for each "." in the key & as such unable to find the tenant for a given domain.  Here is how the mydomains property is parsed in 3.3.7

```
[www:[google:[com:tenant1], abc:[com:tenant2]]]
```

Is there an approach where i could get that same behavior in 3.3.7 ?

Comment: There is some discussion and a work around here https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9537#issuecomment-168604673

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `grailsApplication.config.mydomains['www.abc.com']` use `grailsApplication.config.getProperty('mydomains.www.abc.com')`.

BTW... This isn't directly related to your question but there are very few situations for which referencing `grailsApplication.config` directly is really the best thing to do.  See the article at https://objectcomputing.com/resources/publications/sett/retrieving-config-values-in-grails-3 and the video at https://objectcomputing.com/products/grails/quickcasts/runtime-config-values-grails-3 for more info.  In the video I discuss some of the reasons that directly accessing `grailsApplication.config` isn't usually the best thing.

I hope that helps.

Comment: "getProperty('mydomains.www.abc.com')" seems to work, not ideal but does what we need.